# Does the Deduction Theorem fail for Primitive Recursive Arithmetic?

Tags: logic, foundations

Consider the following iteration of Primitive Recursive Arithmetic. Its primitive rules of inference are *modus ponens* (to infer $\psi$ from $\phi \to \psi$ and $\phi$) and induction (to infer $\phi(t)$ from $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(x) \to \phi(S(x))$). Its logical axioms are as follows:

1. $\phi \to (\psi \to \phi)$
2. $(\phi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to ((\phi \to \psi) \to (\phi \to \chi))$
3. $t = t$
4. $s = t \to (\phi(s,s) \to \phi(s,t))$

In axiom 4, $\phi(s,t)$ is the result of substituting $t$ for at least one instance of $s$ in $\phi(s,s)$, as usual. Its proper axioms are the primitive recursive definitions of each primitive recursive function; for instance, the proper axioms for $+$ are $t + 0 = t$ and $s + S(t) = S(s + t)$. In both the logical and proper axioms, metavariables for formulas and terms have been used in order to do away with unnecessary variable substitution rules (such as: to infer $\phi(t)$ from $\phi(x)$).

My question is as in the title: does the Deduction Theorem fail for Primitive Recursive Arithmetic, and in particular this formulation of it? I know we can prove a restricted version, where we pass from $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$ to $\Gamma \vdash \phi \to \psi$ only if the proof of $\Gamma, \phi \vdash \psi$ does not use the induction rule. But is there a way to prove the general Deduction Theorem, despite this rule?

Comment: I think this the right place for this question, but if you have trouble getting it answered, it's possible that people at cs.stackexchange would be able to answer it, too.

Comment: DT is provable with Ax.1 and 2 and MP only; thus, it holds.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA as I mentioned, the proof I know, which uses *modus ponens* and axioms 1 and 2, is of a restricted version, since the usual proof assumes *modus ponens* is the only rule of inference, which is not the case in PRA. Is there a proof for the Deduction Theorem in PRA without that restriction, what what is it? That would actually answer my question.