# Reverse Mathematics of Well-Founded Induction in Primitive Recursive Arithmetic

Tags: logic, foundations, reverse-math

I have another question about Primitive Recursive Arithmetic, and I'll borrow it's axiomatization from my other question [Does the Deduction Theorem fail for Primitive Recursive Arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4076763/). Consider that definitions of the forms $\phi \mathrel{\leftrightarrow_\mathrm{df}} \psi$ and $a \mathrel{=_\mathrm{df}} b$ introduce, respectively, the implications $\phi \to \psi$ and $\psi \to \phi$, and the equation $a = b$, as proper axioms, as well as extend the language with the new symbols in the definiens (the LHS of the definition). Consider also the following definitions:

1. $1 \mathrel{=_\mathrm{df}} S(0)$
2. $\bot \mathrel{\leftrightarrow_\mathrm{df}} 0 = 1$
3. $(\forall x < 0)\phi(x) \mathrel{\leftrightarrow_\mathrm{df}} \bot$
4. $(\forall x < S(t))\phi(x) \mathrel{\leftrightarrow_\mathrm{df}} (\forall x < t)\phi \land \phi(t)$

In definition 4, $x$ is assumed to not occur free in $t$, so as to avoid defining formulas such as $(\forall x < S(x))\phi$, which would do away with bounded quantification. Furthermore, since my formulation of PRA lacks conjunction as a primitive connective, instead of defining it and laboriously proving its properties, we can, exceptionally for definition 4, introduce instead the three implications $(\forall x < S(t))\phi(x) \to (\forall x < t)\phi$, $(\forall x < S(t))\phi(x) \to \phi(t)$ and $(\forall x < t)\phi \to (\phi(t) \to (\forall x < S(t))\phi(x))$ as proper axioms. This is merely a technical detail and, or so I believe, it shouldn't affect the resolution of this question significantly.

Finally, consider the schema $((\forall x < t)\phi(x) \to \phi(t)) \to \phi(t)$, effectively expressing well-founded induction. Again, $x$ is assumed to not occur free in $t$. If PRA had universal quantifiers, this schema would be equivalent to the formula $(\forall y)(((\forall x < y)\phi(x) \to \phi(y)) \to \phi(y))$.

We can prove this schema from the primitive inference rule of induction (to infer $\phi(t)$ from $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(x) \to \phi(S(x))$), definitions 3 and 4, and some propositional logic. But is the reverse true? Can we do away with the induction inference rule, in PRA, by replacing it with this schema? I suppose that, to do so, one needs at least enough logic (to deal with bounded quantifiers) to have been developed, which would itself require the induction inference rule, and the system resulting from taking the results of this development as primitive would be very similar to the subsystems of first-order arithmetic.

Comment: I have no idea why this got a downvote; I've upvoted to compensate.

Comment: PRA is a quantifier-free formalization of the natural numbers. and it is widely agreed that all reasoning of PRA is finitist, so why are you introducing (bounded) ∀ quantifier to replace the usual PRA induction rule (from $\varphi(0) \land (\varphi(x) \to \varphi (S(x))$ deduce $\varphi(y)$ for any predicate $\varphi$)?

Comment: @mohottnad It would do away with the induction rule by introducing a new proper axiom, so it's interesting from the point of view of alternative axiomatizations of PRA. More personally, I wished to prove that the deduction rule is admissible in PRA, which seems harder to prove under the presence of the induction rule, as the deduction rule is usually shown to be admissible by structural induction and that depends on which primitive inference rules there are in a given axiomatization of PRA.

Comment: Deduction theorem in PRA can be proved using axiom1/2 with modus ponens alone, see [ref](https://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Philosophy/Logic/Deduction/4-deductionTheorem.htm). The logical rules of PRA are only modus ponens and variable substitution together with its logical axioms same as propositional logic and non-logical (proper) axioms similar to PA...

Comment: @mohottnad, note that, in precisely this reference (as well as many other proofs of the deduction theorem), a crucial logical step in the induction step is exactly that the cases are exhaustive, i.e. that, if a formula is inferred from others, then it is only done as such via *modus ponens* and not by any other inference rule. PRA introduces the induction rule and thus this essential logical step cannot simply translate to PRA. This is why I say that "the deduction rule [...] seems harder to prove under the presence of the induction role".

Comment: But the induction rule in PRA is clearly an *admissible* (and even derivable) rule from recursive applications of modus ponens. So although quite technical but like the admissible cut rule in sequent calculus, the set of all *theorems* won't change in PRA by this additional induction rule. Thus DT as a theorem without this rule continues to be a theorem (unlike infinitary ω-rule). To rigorously prove this general conclusion regarding consistency and admissibility of all rules of a logical system one needs proof theory, but here you can imagine an equivalent PRA without such induction rule...

Comment: Skolem's goal of PRA was to eliminate logic entirely from math (at least arithmetic) as a pure recursive computational foundation (no ∀-quantification over infinite domains etc) similar to Poincare's intuitionism, though Poincare like Kant didn't believe in axiomatic need here and considers arithmetic (standard N) is synthetic a priori (unaxiomatizable). In this Skolemic logic-free view if you consider PRA's induction rule is indispensable and underivable, then DT is no longer needed since any implication and other logic connectives can be swept inside the predicate of the induction rule...